# await aborts the function in a React app. why?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, fetch

I am trying to fetch data and set the state in React App. While the fetch is successful, as I can see the data in chrome dev tools, the execution stops at await statement in the below code. Only "getting data" is logged. Looks like after fetch statement the function returns, with all the following steps running successfully.

What am I doing wrong??
Any kind of help is much appreciated.

```
import util from "util";
const fetchProm = util.promisify(fetch)
....
getDataFromDb = async () => {
    console.log('getting data')
    let result = await fetchProm("http://localhost:3001/getData")
      .then(data => {
        console.log("then1:",data)
        return data.json()
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log('then2:', res.data)
        return { data: res.data }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return { err: err.data }
      });
    console.log("result:", result)
    this.setState({ data: result.data })
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not need .then callback if you use async-await.
try below sample :

```
import util from "util";
const fetchProm = util.promisify(fetch)

getDataFromDb = async () => {
    console.log('getting data')
    let {data} = await fetchProm("http://localhost:3001/getData");
    console.log("result:", data)
    this.setState({ data })
  };
```

Comment: that works. but with more modification. I din't have to use promisify either. simply await fetch("http://localhost:3001/getData") works fine. Thanks a ton for the support.

Answer (score 0):

With async/wait you don't need the `then`. Also you catch errors on the second then and not the first.

Can you try:

```
 let result = await fetchProm("http://localhost:3001/getData")

console.log(result)
```

and see if it works?

Comment: that works. but with more modification. I din't have to use promisify either. simply await fetch("http://localhost:3001/getData") works fine. Thanks a ton for the support.

Answer (score 0):

When using `async/await`, don't forget to handle your exceptions with `try/catch`
Change your code to:

```
import util from "util";

getDataFromDb = async () => {
    try{
        let {data} = await fetchProm("http://localhost:3001/getData");
        this.setState({ data })
    }
    catch(err=> this.setState({ err: err.data }))
};
```

Comment: yes i have it in place. I posted minimal code here. anyway, thanks for the feedback.